# could not authenticate you code 32 twitter

Tags: php, json, twitter

Have the following code:

```
  $oauth_nonce = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  $oauth_timestamp = time();            
  $users_ids = implode(',',$users_ids['ids']);
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json';                       
  $oauth_sig_text = self::sign_twitter($url,$oauth_token,false,$oauth_nonce,$oauth_timestamp,$users_ids);     
  $key = __TWITTERSECRET__ . '&' . $oauth_token_secret;            
  $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $oauth_sig_text, $key, true));
  $params = array(                
            'oauth_consumer_key'       => __TWITTERKEY__,
            'oauth_nonce'              => $oauth_nonce,
            'oauth_signature'          => $signature,
            'oauth_signature_method'   => "HMAC-SHA1",
            'oauth_timestamp'          => $oauth_timestamp,
            'oauth_token'              => urlencode($oauth_token),             
            'oauth_version'            => '1.0',
            'user_id'                  => $users_ids
   );        

   $url .= '?'.http_build_query($params);                 
   $users_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);

   echo '<pre>';
          print_r($users_data);
   echo '</pre>';
```

And signature:

```
    protected function sign_twitter($url,$token,$verifier,$nonce,$timestamp,$ids=false){     
        $oauth_base_text = "GET&";
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode($url).'&';            
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_consumer_key='.__TWITTERKEY__.'&');
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_nonce='.$nonce.'&');
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&');
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_timestamp='.$timestamp."&"); 
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_token='.$token."&");                       
        $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('oauth_version=1.0&');

        if ($verifier) {
            $oauth_base_text .= urlencode("oauth_verifier=".$verifier."&");
            $oauth_base_text .= urlencode("oauth_callback=".urlencode(__REDIRECT__)."&");    
        } else {
            $oauth_base_text .= urlencode('user_id=' . $ids);
        }

        return $oauth_base_text;                           
    }
```

I receive an error:

`Array([errors] => Array([0] => Array([message] => Could not authenticate you [code] => 32)))`

if you take a single identifier, the data are given ($users_ids = $users_ids['ids']['0']).
I have read a lot of topics on this issue, and everywhere it is written that the problem in comma that it should be encoded% 2C but it does not help ...

final url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?oauth_consumer_key=Q6KMZzN7AAW******HoxmA&oauth_nonce=ab7e09e8466e0c9893acf3da32de9565&oauth_signature=rhUPhe1HgfcR%2Fr3nkTomuksWPzo%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1378367650&oauth_token=1727480588-IlvYrJZcRnp3dKScJiyZfEEMRpiqlVMTQTr764Q&oauth_version=1.0&user_id=93456690%2C81866717
```

signature:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fusers%2Flookup.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DQ6KMZzN7AAW******HoxmA%26oauth_nonce%3Dab7e09e8466e0c9893acf3da32de9565%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1378367650%26oauth_token%3D1727480588-IlvYrJZcRnp3dKScJiyZfEEMRpiqlVMTQTr764Q%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26user_id%3D93456690%2C81866717
```

Just tried POST request, did not help, all the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate your Authtoken and use the new one and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the [official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) to construct the signature and I was adding `include_entities` for every request which is wrong. I removed it and then everything works fine.